# How to: attach .pdf and send email with no user input needed

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've edited my question based on the feedback. I have a form that I want users to be able to silently (no user input required) save and send with one button click.

The following code is saving as a .pdf with the correct name in the same document/path as the original file (which I want). However when the email is sent, the attachment is the original .docm file instead.

The final attachment must be a .pdf as it will be emailed to a Microsoft Team site and macro-enabled files will not work on Teams.

I'm new to VBA beyond basic commands for my own workflow. I'm working my way through various tutorials/courses and an extremely large book on vba for Office but I would appreciate a fix my newbie coding error sooner rather than later.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

strName = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddName")(1).Range.Text
strDate = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddDate")(1).Range.Text
strTest = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddTestNumber")(1).Range.Text

Dim strFilename As String
strFilename = strName & "_" & "VBATestFile_" & strTest & "_" & Format(strDate, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 strFilename, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF

Dim OL          As Object
Dim EmailItem   As Object
Dim Doc         As Document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save

With EmailItem
    .Subject = strName & " Test" & strTest
    .Body = "Test email send for " & strName & " " & strTest & "."
    .To = "email address here"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Form Submitted", vbInformation

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read the site usage guidelines in the [help], especially the part about asking questions on Stack Overflow. As it stands, this question is "too brorad" - there are too many issues. There should be only ONE issue per question. But you can ask multiple questions. Use the [edit] link below the question to narrow its scope to any one of the issues. You should be able to use the macro recorder to research the syntax for changing the file type. Otherwise, you've done a good job analyzing what you need and formulating the content :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the question. If I can't figure out the answer on my own today, I'll split the question into two parts: saving as a .pdf and saving to the same folder as the original .docm file. The only problems I am really having with the code involve saving the document. After a weekend of not thinking about the problem and with the help of the doorstop-sized VBA for Office book that was delivered over the weekend, I'm hoping I can figure it out on my own. Best way to learn anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

strName = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddName")(1).Range.Text
strDate = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddDate")(1).Range.Text
strTest = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ddTestNumber")(1).Range.Text

Dim strFilename As String 'Create Filename based on data in Content Controls  
strFilename = strName & "_" & "VBATestFile_" & strTest & "_" & format(strDate, "yyyymmdd") & ".pdf"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 strFilename, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF 'Save as .pdf to Documents folder

Dim OL          As Object
Dim EmailItem   As Object
Dim Doc         As Document

Dim sPathUser As String 'Get current file path
sPathUser = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\my documents\"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Silently send email with .pdf file attached
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save

With EmailItem
    .Subject = strName & " Test " & strTest
    .Body = "Test email send for " & strName & " " & strTest & "."
    .To = "email address"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal
    .Attachments.Add strFilename
    .Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Form Submitted", vbInformation 'Confirm document submission for user

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```